# Como realizar una suma de una columa de un csv con una condición if

Tags: python, csv, numpy

Vuelvo a replantear mi pregunta anterior. Tengo un archivo csv con el cual tengo que trabajar con Numpy y no tengo permitido utilizar la librería de pandas.

```
cod_pers,cod_mone,num_mont
2317422,1,628.38
1024726942,1,310.56
2392115,1,46.72
2307784,2,43.22
1024510346,2,27.65
2877641,2,29.41
```

Lo que busco con este csv es poder sumar todos los valores `num_mont` que correspondan al `cod_mone = 1`. Lo cual me debería entregar un resultado de `985.66`.

Para ello generé el código:

```
import csv
import numpy as np

#Leer el archivo CSV
data = np.genfromtxt(archivo.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=None, names=True, encoding="UTF-8")

if (data['cod_mone'] == 1 ):
    resultado = sum(data['num_mont'])

print(resultado)
```

Pero me entrega como resultado:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

¿Cómo podría solucionar este error?, tengo entendido que se debe al uso de ()

Desde ya, muchas gracias!!

Comment: `data['cod_mone']` nombre a la columna completa, que tiene múltiples valores, por lo que compararla contra `1` no tiene sentido.

Comment: Por ejemplo: `df['num_mont'][df['cod_mone'] == 1].sum()`

Comment: Lo que buscaba con eso era poder hacer el filtro que quiero, que solamente los cod_mone = 1 se sumen, que se pueda sumar 628.38+310.56+46.72 y me entregue el resultado de 985.66

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomando el comentario de Patricio

```
import numpy as np

data = np.genfromtxt('arch.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=None, names=True, encoding="UTF-8")
resultado = data['num_mont'][data['cod_mone'] == 1].sum()
print(resultado)
```

produce:

```
985.6600000000001

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Una consulta, ¿Cómo podría hacer para que en vez de que sea en una sola condición, pueda ser entre varias condiciones?

Comment: @IgnacioZumelzu. No conozco numpy. Simplemente leí el primer capítulo del tutorial y busque en Internet (y copie lo de Patricio). Si vas a trabajar con numpy, mejor lo estudias.